# How to get ACTION_UP Touch Event for NestedScrollview

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, android-nestedscrollview

I want to click the parent view (LinearLayout) listener but unable to click because of NestedScrollView(Child).
so I tried to OnTouch NestedScrollView but I only get the ACTION_MOVE but I need ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN event for performing function

I tried by creating custom NestedScrollView and Override OnInterceptTouch events and requestDisallow(false)

xml

https://pastebin.com/WYabtJM0

```
nestedScrollView?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (bind?.mainViewModel?.buttonTappedToCheckForRestriction?.value != false && bind?.mainViewModel?.visbility?.value != false) {
                    bind?.mainViewModel?.buttonTappedToCheckForRestriction?.postValue(true)
                } else if (bind?.mainViewModel?.visbility?.value == true) {
                    bind?.mainViewModel?.buttonTappedToCheckForRestriction?.postValue(true)
                }
            }
        }
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    };
```

Comment: share your xml file please

Comment: @Kirguduck I edited my question please review it

Answer (score 0):

To identify the user manipulating the NeedScrollView you should overight this function

```
scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(object : NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener{
@Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
        }
        if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
        }

        if (scrollY == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
        }

       if (scrollY == ( v.getMeasuredHeight() - v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() )) {
           Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
       }
   }

})
```